How do you drain a fuel tank on a Cessna 172R?
Our 172 "R" model has 5 sump drains on each tank.  I leveled the airplane according to the POH, removed the sump drain located next to the inlet hose by the fuselage and drained the tank dry. Is this the proper way to drain a tank to "empty"?  Or should the airplane not be leveled in order to let any residual fuel move to the rear of the tank for drainage?  There is no published guidance that I can find to drain a tank to "empty".

@JohnK I have posted a similar pic here before, I fly the same model. There's 5 each wing and 2 under the fuselage.

I also reviewed the maintenance manual and studied Chapter 28 - Fuel Systems, more carefully.  Under "Fuel Quantity Calibration" it does say to remove all fuel drains on the wings and the from the fuel selector too.  However, it also says to level the airplane first and then tilt the nose up  by 2 degrees before adding fuel.  Previous guidance was to keep the airplane in a level attitude during fueling.  Maybe the tilting will make a difference.  I am going to try to recalibrate next week.
